# Undo/Redo not working in object mode and Weight Paint mode on MacOS

Tags: mesh, edit-mode, object-mode

I am facing an issue in Blender version 3.6.5, where if I make any changes in Object mode or Weight Paint mode, it cannot undo or redo to the changes I made, and on many occasions, it crashes when I press <kbd>Ctrl/Cmd</kbd>  + <kbd>Z</kbd> for undo.

Also, any changes made in the *Object Mode* or *Weight Paint* mode, do not show the changes in Undo history. So when I press *Undo*, it jumps back to the last *Edit Mode* state or sculpt mode state of the mesh or Blender crashes.

What is the solution?

System info:
CPU: M2 Max
GPU: Apple 30 Core
OS: Sonoma 14.1.1
Blender version using: Blender 3.6.5